# Qt Creator Refactoring: Extract function

Tags: c++, qt, refactoring, extract

i wonder whether there is a refactoring option to extract a function from a marked area in the c++ qt-creator. (i.e. like in eclipse).
I already found a hint that i interpreted as "it's possible" in "http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-editor-refactoring.html -> search for 'Extract Function'". But actually i couldn't find any option to do so.
Neither right-click/Refactoring nor [menuebar]extra/c++.

Does somebody knows something about it? Is it only in payed qt creators? Or is it supposed to appear in the refactoring dialoge but it dosn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the project I use consists of header files that use inline definitions. Therefore I cant extract functions while they are inlined!
If I had simple definitions in .cpp files that there would be no problem :)
(I tried it).